# Convert sp_OACreate 'Scripting.FileSystemObject' to C#

Tags: c#, wpf, stored-procedures

I am working on a task that convert sql store procedure to C# code and stuck in this line:

```
execute @liRetCode = sp_OACreate 'Scripting.FileSystemObject' , @liFileSystem output
```

So can you please show me how to convert it in C#? I tried FileSystemObject in Scripting library but couldn't use CreateObject method.

I also tried

```
Type scriptingType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
dynamic scriptingTypeObject = Activator.CreateInstance(scriptingType);
```

but have idea how to get FileSystem and RetCode.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps there is a better way to do this. I wouldn't recommend creating any OLE objects like this in C# code when there is likely a built-in API that you can use. What does your code do in terms of functionality, is it just creating a file on the file system, reading from that file or what? =]

Comment: Thanks Sean, so do we have alternative way for this using built-in API?

Comment: Well I can't tell what your code ends up doing from the code you've provided, so far you're just creating the file system object. Does the code after this create a file or modify a file or something? There are plenty of file system classes and methods in the System.IO namespace =] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.aspx